# append predictions to new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, regression, data-science

[Data example (not real data) can be also seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ETrp.png) I have a data set of 3x500 with columns names of : Job Level (numerical), Job Code (Categorical) and Stock Value (Numerical). I am using linear regression to fit the Stock values based on Job Levels, grouped by Job Code. 
For example:

Job Code    Job Level   Job Title    Stock Value

20     1    Production   Engineer

20     2    Production   Engineer

20     3    Production   Engineer     6,985

20     4    Production   Engineer     7,852

20     5    Production   Engineer

30     1    Production   Engineer

30     2    Logistics    Analyst

30     3    Logistics    Analyst      4,962

30     4    Logistics    Analyst      22,613

30     5    Logistics    Analyst      31,689

40     1    Logistics    Analyst

Here is what I have done. How can I get to see my data set columns (original data) with the predicted values added. Right now I only can see the prediction. I can not join them together because:

**Here is the situation:** When I first start my code my df_nonull.shape = (268,4) then after the for loop my df_nonull.shape = (4,4) and then df_results.shape = (89,2). As a result, I am not able to join them.

```
> import pandas as pd from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
> df = pd.read_excel("stats.xlsx")
> df_nonull=df.dropna()
> 
> model= LinearRegression() groups = [] results = [] level = []
> 
> for (group, df_nonull) in df_nonull.groupby('Job Code'):
>     X=df_nonull[['Job Level']]
>     y=df_nonull[['Stock Value']]
>     model.fit(X,y)
>     coefs = list(zip(X.columns, model.coef_))
>     results.append(model.predict(735947)[0])
>     groups.append(group)
> 
> df_results = pd.DataFrame({'Job Code':groups, 'prediction':results})
> 
> print df_results.head(50)
```

Just FYI, my main goal here is running a regression model in the data set where there is no NaN (df_nonull), and applying the linear regression coefficients to the entire data (for Stock Values,y) (df). This has nothing to do with what I am asking but wanted to give some backround info about why I am pursuing this.

Comment: i think the predict function returns  indexable object...what you have to do is get the index of your prediction and use them in the original X

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have consistent index for the input data and the prediction series. I think what you need is `pd.concat`.

```
import pandas as pd

>>> X = pd.DataFrame({'input': [i for i in range(10)]}) ## fake input data
>>> pred = pd.DataFrame({'prediction':[i-5 for i in range(10)]}) ## fake prediction data
>>> pd.concat([X, pred], axis=1)
   input  prediction
0      0          -5
1      1          -4
2      2          -3
3      3          -2
4      4          -1
5      5           0
6      6           1
7      7           2
8      8           3
9      9           4
```

I would recommend the pandas (0.20.1) specifically this section on [concatenation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects).

Comment: Thanks alot, this is helpful. Here is the situation: When I first start my code my df_nonull.shape = (268,4) then after the for loop my  df_nonull.shape = (4,4) and then df_results.shape = (89,2). As a result, I am not able to join them. Why did the shape of the original df_nonull changed from (268,4) to (4,4)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use then following command to create one single data frame containing the data set values and the predicted values.

`df_nonull.join(df_results,how="outer")`

Comment: Thanks alot, this is helpful. Here is the situation: When I first start my code my df_nonull.shape = (268,4) then after the for loop my df_nonull.shape = (4,4) and then df_results.shape = (89,2). As a result, I am not able to join them. Why did the shape of the original df_nonull changed from (268,4) to (4,4)?